# Determine whether the series $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ converges or diverges. If it converges, find the bounds for the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ converges or diverges. If it converges, find the bounds for the sum of the series.

A) Converges, $\frac3{2}$ < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < $\frac5{2}$

B) Converges, 2 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 3

C) Converges, 4 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 6

D) Converges, 6 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 8

E) The series diverges

I know the series converges. Using p-Series, p=$\frac3{2}$ meaning that p>1 therefore the series converges. However, I don't know how to find the bounds for the sum of the series

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Because $k^{-3/2}$ is decreasing, you have $$\int_k^{k+1}x^{-3/2}dx \le k^{-3/2} \le \int_{k-1}^k x^{-3/2}.$$

What does this mean for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2k^{-3/2} = 2+2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k^{-3/2}$?